# How to use "occasional" as a doer of a particular activity?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

Is it correct to say for example: "I am an occasional music composer"?
I mean is it correct to use occasional as a maker or doer of something?

I have already checked the Merriam Webster Dictionary and this is the result:

Definition of occasional
1a: of or relating to a particular occasion
a budget able to meet occasional demands as well as regular ones*

b: created for a particular occasion*
occasional verse
occasional music

2: acting as the occasion or contributing cause of something
occasional causes for creating apparent effects

3: encountered, occurring, appearing, or taken at irregular or infrequent intervals
occasional visitors
an occasional vacation
found occasional errors
occasional episodes of chest pain

4: acting in a specified capacity from time to time
an occasional lecturer
an occasional essayist

5: designed or constructed to be used as the occasion demands
occasional furniture

Comment: This is a very confusing question.  **OP is not aware** that "occasional" is used as a signifier, exactly like "sometime", "keen", "amateur", "retired" or "half-assed".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could say occasional but you may be mistaken for a professional composer of occasional music (music that is composed for a particular occasion, such as weddings)

The word composer is usually understood to mean "composer of music" so you could just say "I am an occasional composer" or "I compose music on occasion" but this would just mean that you don't do it that often.

"I am an amateur composer"

"I am a hobbyist composer"

"I am a weekend composer"

would all convey that you don't do this professionally.

Comment: yes, this is what I meant: "I am an amateur composer who actually makes a song in his free time."

Comment: "I compose music as a hobby" or "In my free time, I like to compose music and write songs"

Comment: By the way, is it common or correct to say "I am an occasional composer of music" meaning that I do this kind of action not very often, or is it still conveying the meaning that I am a professional music composer who can compose music for occasions like a wedding?

Comment: It's correct in that people will understand what you mean (the ambiguity is only slight) but it doesn't sound natural. If you compose music, you're always a composer. You don't only transform into one when you're in the act of writing a song. A more natural-sounding way to say it would be "I compose music on occasion" or "I sometimes compose music".

Comment: Also, the word 'composer' in English mainly refers to instrumental 'serious' music. We usually use 'song' for popular music with lyrics, and call people who create it 'songwriters'.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100290/discussion-between-a-leo-and-burt-carlson).

Comment: Obviously the "occasional music" aspect is totally irrelevant to what the OP is asking about in general terms.

Answer (score 1):

> *He is **an occasional** X = **Occasionally**, he is an X*
>
> **occasionally** ([Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/occasionally))
>    *sometimes but not often or regularly*

OP's cited definition of **occasional** as "of or relating to a particular occasion" is perhaps misleading as regards the idiomatic use of *an occasional [noun]*, where all it really signifies is *on **particular** occasions / at **certain** times*, by way of contrast with ***all the time, continuously***.

---

Note that the construction [*He was an **occasional** X*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=He%20was%20an%20occasional&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CHe%20was%20an%20occasional%3B%2Cc0) has been in steady decline for over a century (it's something of an ["elevated register", "posh talk"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_(sociolinguistics)))...
[image]

...while the (still slightly "slangy") alternative [*He was a **sometime** X*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=was%20a%20sometime&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwas%20a%20sometime%3B%2Cc0) has steadily been *gaining* ground...
[image]

Comment: The definition was slightly ambiguous to me. Is it meant that saying "I am an occasional X" is no longer spoken among people?

Comment: It's much less common than it used to be. And there ***is*** such a thing as "occasional music" (another relatively uncommon / "posh" term, meaning *music composed **for special occasions*** - such as a new monarch taking the throne). So *in theory* your example could be "ambiguous" as well as "unfamiliar" even to many native speakers. In practice though, it's usually just a relatively upmarket format whereby people might self-deprecatingly say *I'm an occasional X* to mean *From time to time I do things that an X would do, but I'm not a professional, and I don't do them often (or *well* :)

Comment: This is an extremely confusing question.  OP *is not* asking about the form "occasional profession-X".  (Which is rather like, say, "sometime profession-X".)   OP is just asking a question about "how to use the word occasional" where, in OP's question example, "occasion" happens to proceed a profession-X-word.  @FumbleFingers , I know you understand what I'm saying right?  :)

Comment: @Fattie: 'Fraid I don't understand! OP says he's asking about contexts where the noun in *an occasional X* represents "a maker or doer of something". I imagine by far the most common value for ***X*** is ***visitor*** (one who makes visits / does the act of visiting) - hardly what I'd call a "profession".